# Add elements into an array then find distinct,

Tags: microsoft-dynamics, navision, microsoft-dynamics-nav, dynamics-business-central

```
On an Item Card Page, there is a selection of Item Category which has a Code field.
```

So in Sales Quote I have selected 2 items;
1) Front Hub
2) Bicycle
    and these two items have a Item Category Code set (lets say Chair, Desk respectively) in their Item Card Page. I will print Chair / Desk in the report of Sales Quote.

I am approaching this be first finding Item Category Codes for the Line Items and then putting them in an array, then I will compare and move distinct ones (reason for finding distinct is if 2 items have same Item Category Codes I have to print that Code ONLY once, so if 3 Line Items have Desk, Desk, Chair, I will print on the report Desk / Chair) into another array then concatenate the values with ' / ' into a Text Variable.
Here is what I have done so far but got stuck in getting right values into my array.

```
On the OnAfterGetRecord Trigger of my Sales Quote Report
I have written;
ItemCateTableRec.Reset();
ItemCateTableRec.SetFilter(Code, "Sales Line"."Item Category Code");
IF ItemCateTableRec.FindSet then begin
repeat
myArray [ i ] := ItemCateTableRec.Code;
i := i + 1;
until ItemCateTableRec.Next = 0;
end;
```

Upon printing the myArray[1] and [2] I do not get the correct Item Category Code Chair for my Item FrontHub and Desk for my Item Bicycle. I get incorrect values.
Thanks a ton in advance for any guidance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What you are looking for is not array. It is [temporary table](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dynamics-nav/temporary-tables).

You need to define table variable of Item Category as temporary and then just

```
If not TempCategoryCode.Insert then ; //do nothing
```

This will get you a table filled with unique codes.